# Why does ortools set constraint rigidly?

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

I went through [google ortools scheduling tutorial](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling) and created slightly different constraint.

Say, that we have a df, that indicates the following:

1. Each nurse can work only on the preassigned shift. According to the table, nurse 0 must work either on shift 0 or 1, the nurse 2 must work only on the shift 2 etc.
2. Furthermore, I added the following constraint: "If nurse_0 takes shift_0, then she must take shif_1". It's shown by column "is_child" - shift_1 is child_shift for shift_0 for nurse_0.

> ```
>  df_dict = {
>             "slot_number":[1,1,2,2,3],
>             "asset_name":['0','1','0','1','2'],
>             "is_child":["No","No","Yes",'No','No']
>            }
>
>   df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
> ```

Create variables and a model:

```
num_nurses = 3
num_shifts = 3
all_nurses = range(num_nurses)
all_shifts = range(num_shifts)

model = cp_model.CpModel()

shifts = {}
for n in all_nurses:
    for s in all_shifts:
        shifts[(n, s)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_n%is%i' % (n, s))
```

One nurse can take only one shift:

```
for s in all_shifts:
    model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 1)
```

***My constraint***:

```
# whether the slot (key) have any children in other slots
children = {0: [1], 1: [] ,2: []} 
#  what nurses are considered the children (values) in which slot (key)
nurse_child_sched = {0:[], 1:[0], 2:[]} 
# In this case if nurse 0 take slot 0, then she must take slot 1 too.
for s in all_shifts:
    for n in all_nurses:
        if (children[s]):
            for child in children[s]:
                if n in nurse_child_sched[child]:
                    model.Add((shifts[(n,s)] + shifts[(n,child)])==2)
                    print(f"{s}-parent_slot and {child}-child_slot were connected for nurse {n}")
```

The code to create schedules and show solutions:

```
class NursesPartialSolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
"""Print intermediate solutions."""

def __init__(self, shifts, num_nurses, num_shifts, sols):
    cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
    self._shifts = shifts
    self._num_nurses = num_nurses
    self._num_shifts = num_shifts
    self._solutions = set(sols)
    self._solution_count = 0

def on_solution_callback(self):
    if self._solution_count in self._solutions:
        print('Solution %i' % self._solution_count)

        for n in range(self._num_nurses):
            is_working = False
            for s in range(self._num_shifts):
                if self.Value(self._shifts[(n, s)]):
                    is_working = True
                    print('  Nurse %i works shift %i' % (n, s))
            if not is_working:
                print('  Nurse {} does not work'.format(n))
        print()
    self._solution_count += 1

def solution_count(self):
    return self._solution_count

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.parameters.linearization_level = 0
a_few_solutions = range(5)
solution_printer = NursesPartialSolutionPrinter(shifts, num_nurses, num_shifts,a_few_solutions)

solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)
```

And, finally, I have the following result:

```
Solution 0
  Nurse 0 works shift 0
  Nurse 0 works shift 1
  Nurse 1 works shift 2
  Nurse 2 does not work

Solution 1
  Nurse 0 works shift 0
  Nurse 0 works shift 1
  Nurse 1 does not work
  Nurse 2 works shift 2

Solution 2
  Nurse 0 works shift 0
  Nurse 0 works shift 1
  Nurse 0 works shift 2
  Nurse 1 does not work
  Nurse 2 does not work
```

***However, according to my logic, there must be also at least the solution below. I realize, that my constraint says the model to put nurse_0 on shift_0, but I need to just put the relation between two slots in case if nurse_0 is putted on first shift and no constraints otherwise. Thanks in advance.***

> ```
> Solution x
>   Nurse 1 works shift 0
>   Nurse 0 works shift 1
>   Nurse 0 works shift 2
>   Nurse 1 does not work
>   Nurse 2 does not work
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Side note:

> One nurse can take only one shift:

```py
  for s in all_shifts:
    model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 1)
```

Here you have written "each shift is assigned to exactly one nurse"

If you wan to express "one nurse can take only one shift" you should write:

```py
for n in all_nurses:
    model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, s)] for s in all_shifts) == 1)
```

note: but in this case since nurse exactly work one shift, child shift is impossible so I guess your code is OK and not the comment...